# tabs create event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need add `create` event processing after `tabs` init. I do this

```
$("#payment-popup").tabs({
    heightStyle: "content",
    activate: function(event ,ui){
        $(this).find($(".ui-tabs-nav")).toggleClass("hidden2");
        $("#payment-popup-menu-button").toggleClass("hidden2");

    }

});
```

...

```
(function($){
    $("#payment-popup").on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {alert('alert 1')} );
    $("#payment-popup").on( "tabscreate", function( event, ui ) {alert('create fire')} );
})(jQuery);
```

but no alert. What is wrong?

Comment: Hello @Oleksandr, where did these tabs come from? is it from jQuery-ui?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to add / trigger your own custom event using jQuery, you might want to look here : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @TimothyGroote I follow this manual http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create so I suppose it should be already triggered by `tabs` plugin

Comment: Ah, very well. are you sure you attach the listener (your second bit of code) *before* you reach the first bit of code?

Comment: @TimothyGroote see my edit on second piece of the code. Event `acitvate` fires well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect this code to work if entered in this order :

(i have added the document ready listener because it is a way to make certain that the element has been loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       //no need to look up the same element twice.
       var paymentPopupElement = $("#payment-popup")

       paymentPopupElement.on("tabscreate", function( event, ui ) {alert("create fire")} );

       paymentPopupElement.tabs({
        heightStyle: "content",
        activate: function(event ,ui)
        {
            $(this).find($(".ui-tabs-nav")).toggleClass("hidden2");
            $("#payment-popup-menu-button").toggleClass("hidden2");

        }
       });

});
```